# Error while Parsing SQL query string PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion

I tried to execute code below.

```
var sqlText = "SELECT user_id, role_id FROM app_user WHERE user_roles ?? role_id::text AND role_is_active = 'Y' AND user_id = :user_id";

queryExecute( sqlText, {user_id: { value: 24, cfsqltype: "integer" }}, {datasource : "test_db"});
```

Each time I tried to run the query the error message occurred.

```
Detail: Lesser number (1) of positional parameters are defined for sql query':' [SELECT user_id, role_id FROM app_user WHERE user_roles ?? role_id::text AND role_is_active = 'Y' AND user_id = ?]
Message: Error while Parsing SQL query string.
```

I tried executing the query in DBeaver and worked as expected. Then I tried eliminating the parameters in the Where clause. Once I removed the `user_roles ?? role_id::text` the query executed just fine. I'm wondering why query is failing to execute with this filter `user_roles ?? role_id::text` in it? Is there something that I have to change? Thank you.